# Trying to figure out how to make a hamburger menu stay stationary once it is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

From this demo

```
https:// codepen.io/ducktectiveQuack/pen/mPGMRZ
```

I can't figure out the code block so I made cheating (just delete the space between the '/' and the 'c' lol)

I am trying to make it so that once you click on the hamburger menu, the drop-down appears but nothing more. The menu shifts to the right and then it shift again after you hover over the social tab. I just want it to remain stationary the entire time, even after it drops-down.

I am still pretty new to HTML/CSS and especially JavaScript (my prof helped me with this) so my apologies if this seems like a really basic question.

I thought that simply putting 'position:fixed' or 'position:absolute' would do the trick but it does not haha.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I cannot see the page from the codepen.

Answer (score -1):

> the dropdown appears but nothing more. as you can see, right now the
>   menu shifts to the right. it then shifts again after you hover over
>   the social tab. I just wan it to remain stationary the entire time,
>   even after it drops down.

Try setting `#menu` `position` to `absolute` , `.nav li:hover ul` `position` to `absolute`, `top` to `200px`, `left` to `0px`. Note, `html` is missing closing `</header>` tag.

```
 #menu {
    position:absolute;
 }

.nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:0px;
  }
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "80px";
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}

#menu {
  position:absolute;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:0px;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Banana | Home</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("img/vicmensa.jpg");
    background-color: #515151;
  }
  header {
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 60px;
    position: fixed;
  }
  #container {
    margin: 150px 0px 0px 400px;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
  .title-block {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 30px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #00b4ff;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 24pt;
  }
  .text-block {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16pt;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14pt;
  }
  .nav a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav ul {
    display: none;
    background: none;
  }
  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;

  }
  
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00b4ff;
  }
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .burger-button {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
  .x-button {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <header>
    <button class="burger-button" onclick="
    if (document.getElementById('menu').style.display=='block')
    {
     document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none'
    }
    else
    {
     document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block'
                    /*make the hamburger icon an X and get it to stop moving positions*/
                }
  "><a href="#"><span style = "color: white;">&#9776;</span></a>
      </button>
      <!-- nav -->
      <ul class="nav" id="menu">
        <li> <a href="/"> Home </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="music.html"> Music </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="pictures.html"> Pictures </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="projects.html"> Projects </a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="resume.html"> Resume </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Social + </a> 
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Facebook </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Twitter </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> Instagram </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"> LinkedIn </a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- end nav -->
  </header>

  <div id="container">
    <div class="title-block">
      first middle last
      <hr style="width: 100%; height: 2px; background-color: white; border-radius: 2px; margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;">
    </div>
    <div class="text-block">
      <span style="color: #00b4ff"><em> noun </em></span> 
      <br>city, state
      <br>junior at <a href="http://www.usc.edu">university</a> 
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZXvOR

Comment: Thank you, was such a simple fix that I feel pretty dumb now haha...

I didn't think I also had to specify it in the id, just the class.

Comment: @AaronL See updated post, also set `ul` at `:hover` at "Social" to remain fixed.